# how do I use resources.load to call a 2D sprite from the asset folder to the camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

like it is from the title,

how can I use the script resources.load to call on items which exist in the assets folder to be called runtime into the camera ?

if not resource.load is there any other way to load items on runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

Resources.Load only can retrieve assets stored in the Resources folder under Assets. That is because the path is used by the method. You can have sub folder and provide the path in the url of your asset but you cannot store something under Assets/MyFolder/SomeTexture.png and use Resources.Load to find it. In this case, you'd have to create a reference and drag the asset into it in inspector.

The difference between Resources folder assets and others is that whatever is inside Resources is packed and shipped with the project. The reason is that Unity is no able to know if the app will use it, so to avoid a null reference, it goes with.

Assets contained within the Assets folder are only shipped if Unity finds a reference in code in the Inspector via a drag. This makes the build smaller as it is also compressed with better algorithm.